# Convert DataRowCollection to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5, ienumerable

I would like to do something like this in .NET 3.5. What's the quickest way?

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> collection = 
    TypedDataSet.TypedTableBase<DataRow>.Rows as IEnumerable<DataRow>;
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Assuming you're using .NET 4.0, which introduces covariance:

```
// Presumably your table is of some type deriving from TypedTableBase<T>,
// where T is an auto-generated type deriving from DataRow.
IEnumerable<DataRow> collection = myTypedTable;
```

The [table type itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358258.aspx) implements `IEnumerable<T> where T : DataRow`.

Otherwise:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> collection = myTypedTable.Cast<DataRow>();
```

Comment: This and wsanville's answers were relevant for me. It happens that Cast<TResult> throws an exception when it finds an item which cannot be cast to TResult. On the other hand, OfType<DataRow> only returns items which are of type TResult. See the documentation on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 102):

You can call `OfType<DataRow>()` on the `DataRowCollection`.

Comment: This is the simplest solution

Comment: This is really no different than calling Cast<DataRow>() on the DataRowCollection, which is already in the accepted answer.

(except if we're splitting hairs, I believe OfType does some unnecessary filtering that Cast doesn't bother with)

Comment: @KevinHolt no I would say they are the same if and only if you know for certain the only type of objects in the collection are castable to DataRows... in the case of a DataRowCollection, that's true, but in most non-generic `IEnumerable`s it definitely isn't.

Comment: Right I'm not saying that IEnumerable<T>.OfType<R>() and IEnumerable<T>.Cast<R>() always do the same thing for any T and R, and I wasn't trying to imply that. However, I am saying (and it sounds like you agree with me) that they do the same thing in the case where R=T, such as the OP's actual question which I read as asking specifically about T=R=DataRow.

Answer (score 5):

A simple direct solution is to use the method "Select()" of a `System.Data.DataTable` object, which produces `DataRow[]`. From this you can treat as an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` using Linq like below:

```
List<MyItem> items = dtItems.Select()
                            .Select(row => new MyItem(row))
                            .ToList();
```

Providing a useful list of objects for each row.

Comment: The problem using .Select() is that if the data is ordered in the Datatable, it will lose it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in extension method if you include `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` in to your project that adds a `AsEnumerable()` method.

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> collection = TypedDataSet.TypedTableBase<DataRow>.AsEnumerable();
```