# DataTable select with LiNQ and check is there duplicate rows or not

Tags: c#, linq

I used **.Net framwork 4.0 with** WinForm application component `DataGridView` and set `DataSource` with `DataTable`.Then there's a button to add row into `DataGridView`.

That code like this.

```
gridTable = (DataTable)dgrMainGrid.DataSource; 
DataRow dr = gridTable.NewRow();
```

Before adding **New Row** into **DataTable** I checked if there's a duplicate row.To do that I used this `LINQ` Query.

```
//Item Code cannot duplicate
var results = from itmCode in gridTable.AsEnumerable()
              where (itmCode.Field<string>("Item Code") == txtGrdItmLoc.Text)
              select itmCode;
```

**There after how I check the duplicate rows available or not in the data table?**

```
if(//doWhatever function here ){
  //if there's duplicate row values 
  isNotDuplicate = false;
}
else{
  isNotDuplicate=true;
}
```

**Before go to following step** I need to get **is there a duplicate or not and set it into isNotDuplicate variable or similar thing to check that.** so i think to count the `results` rows but there's no such function to count 'var results`, Any possibility to do that?

```
if (!isDuplicate)
{
     dr["#"] = true;
     dr["Item Code"] = lSysItemCode;
     dr["Stock Code"] = txtGdrItmItemLoc.Text;
     dr["Brand"] = txtGrdItmBrand.Text;
     dr["Model No"] = cmbGrdItmModel.SelectedValue.ToString();
     gridTable.Rows.Add(dr);
     dgrMainGrid.DataSource = gridTable;
}
```

> I can use `for loop` with `DataTable` and check whether it's contain new value that equals to **"Item Code"** but I looking alternative method with linq.

**Simply I'm looking replacement for this by using linq.**

```
foreach (DataRow r in gridTable.Rows) {
             if (r["Item Code"].ToString() == txtGrdItmLoc.Text) {
                    isDuplicate = true;
             }
        }
```

> Sample Project : http://1drv.ms/1K4JnHt
>
> Sample Code : http://pastebin.com/v7NMdUrf

Comment: `gridTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(g => g.Field<string>("Item Code")).Where(g => g.Count() > 0)` Will return you duplicates.

Comment: Duplicate as in..? All rows with same `Item Code`?

Comment: When I added new item.I need to check that item already in the data table column "Item Code"

Comment: @Jimmer - Okay then the first query in my answer should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You have not made it clear that in your DataTable if you are looking for duplicates for any specific `Item Code` or for any Item Code. Anyways,here is the code for both the scenarios:-

If you are looking for duplicates for any specific `Item Code` then you can simply check the count like this:-

```
bool istxtGrdItmLocDuplicate = gridTable.AsEnumerable()
                        .Count(x => x.Field<string>("ItemCode") == txtGrdItmLoc.Text) > 1;
```

If you are looking for duplicates in the entire DataTable, then simply group by `Item Code` and check the respective count for each Item Code like this:-

```
bool isDuplicate = gridTable.AsEnumerable()
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("ItemCode")
                            .Any(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

Comment: 'EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy' and no extension method 'GroupBy' accepting a first argument of type 'EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @GuidoG - Have u added reference to _System.Linq_ ? I am sure you are missing that.

Comment: yes that was it. This happens so much they should fix it so it wont compile without that using and give a warning that you are missing a using...

Comment: @GuidoG - But Visual Studio add these namespaces by default ;) And it will give you suggestion if you press _Ctrl + . _

Comment: I got VS 2015 pro and it never does that for me. Some setting maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

First cast it to IEnumerable :

[Convert DataRowCollection to IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974159/convert-datarowcollection-to-ienumerablet)

Then you can use LINQ extension methods to do something like this (to check all values that has duplicates):

```
var duplicates = resultsList.Where(r => resultsList.Count(r2 => r2.Field<string>("Item Code") == r.Field<string>("Item Code")) > 0);
```

If you want check each value for duplicate you can use `.Count` method, something like this:

```
bool hasDuplicates = resultsList.Count(r2 => r2.Field<string>("Item Code") == "your code") > 1;
```

Ok, if for some reason this doesn't work you can write this function yourself:

```
public static class Helper
{
                                    // or other collection type
    public static int MyCount<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, bool> function)
    {            
        int count = 0;
        foreach (T i in collection)
            if (function(i)) ++count;
        return count;
    }
}
```

And use it like :

```
results.MyCount(r => r.Field<string>("Item Code") == "Item Code");
```

Comment: Error: System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type.*What's you used .net framework version ?*

Comment: That's odd, try to convert it with.ToList() method first... I'll update my answer... I used .Net 4.5 ... Updated my answer with .ToList() method

Comment: There's not method ToList()

Comment: What version of .Net framework your project uses? `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>` class implements interface `IEnumerable<T>` and this interface has lot's of extension methods from LINQ (like .Where .Count .ToList) that's why it **should** work...

Comment: Updated my answer with custom `Count()` method this should be enough to understand the general idea...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85272/discussion-between-jimmer-and-fabjan).

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable<T>` has a `Count()` method ([check here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx)), if you are not seeing it in intellisense then you are missing some `using` instruction, like `using System.Linq;` or some other...

Then you would just do:

```
if(results.Count()>0){
 //if there's duplicate row values 
 isNotDuplicate = false;
}
else
{
  isNotDuplicate=true;
}
```

Comment: `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>` not contain method Count()

Comment: `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` so it MUST contain that method. I repeat, if you don't see it in intellisense, you are missing something, but it is there.

Comment: Yes I dint's see it( Count() ) in intellisense.But there's no error.