# Convert for loop to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, autocomplete

I am trying to avoid the for loop and use LINQ instead of for loop. Any help will be highly appreciated. I have been trying to use dt.select (a=>...) but it is always throwing error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not delegate type".

```
    AutoCompleteStringCollection coll = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();  
    cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=XYX;Integrated 
    Security=True");
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select UserName from ServiceProviders order 
    by UserName asc", cn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
             coll.Add(dt.Rows[i]["UserName"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: So you want to loop over every row and add the username field to the coll collection?  You want to do a loop without a loop?

Comment: I guess that here is a tip which you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974159/convert-datarowcollection-to-ienumerablet/4974176

Comment: LINQ would only make sense here if `coll` is of type List<>, because of its AddRange method taking an IEnumerable which is the basic data structure of LINQ. In this case your loop (and the if block around) can be replaced by `coll.AddRange(dt.Rows.Select(row => row["UserName"].ToString()));`. But like Hogan said under the hood the same happens like in his solution.

Comment: getting error that dt,rows does not contains definition of Select.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want an easy way to do this loop, I'd use `foreach` instead of `if` and `for`.  The nice thing about foreach is that you don't have to check count.  If there are none it won't execute.  The code should look something like this:

```
foreach( var row in dt.Rows)
{
   coll.Add(row["Username"].ToString());
}
```

Remember this -- Linq is not about about removing flow of control (loops) from your code -- the loop still exists.  Linq is about expressions and expressions that can include loops or flow of control.  (I know, it is subtle).

Bottom line -- if you need a loop, you need a loop.  Linq does not "remove" that need.

Comment: Thanks! Getting an error with it. Can;t apply indexing with [].

Comment: @Gaurav -- can I see your exact code? In the loop in debugging row should be of type DataRow, if not then you have a typo.

Answer (score 0):

To do a `linq` query against a `DataTable` you need to call `.AsEnumerable()` on it first.  I notice your `coll` is not a `List<string>` but you're adding your selection to it as a `string`, you may want to look into that, but to answer your specific question, here is a basic example that queries against a `DataTable` and adds specific rows to a `List<T>`.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("UserName");
dt.Columns.Add("Bar");
dt.Rows.Add("Bob", 1);
dt.Rows.Add("Bill", 2);
dt.Rows.Add("John", 3);

var foo = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["UserName"]).ToList();
var bar = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["Bar"]).ToList();
```