# Why can I not iterate over something with linq that can be iterated over with foreach?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, datarowcollection

I have a collection of table rows (type `DataRowCollection`). It is perfectly valid for me to write:

```
foreach(var row in myDataRowCollection)
{
  // Something with row
}
```

Yet the following will not compile:

```
myDataRowCollection.ToList();
```

or even

```
myDataRowCollection.Select(...
```

What are these System.Linq extensions expecting that `DataRowCollection` doesn't implement?

Comment: Not compile means? is it throwing any exception? if yes then provide error.

Comment: It simple isn't valid code, if I write .Select (even after including the System.Linq namespace) it has a red line under it, it's not valid, it won't build.

Comment: No, System.Linq has been added.

Comment: Not sure why I received a downvote for this - I don't mind downvotes if they're explained with constructive criticism but can't see what's wrong here!?

Comment: `myDataRowCollection.Cast<DataRow>().ToList()` ... extensions are for `IEnumerable<T>` not `IEnumerable`

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974159/convert-datarowcollection-to-ienumerablet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foreach()` is pattern based ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)), it does not actually rely on `IEnumerable`. `GetEnumerator()` is enough.

```
class A // note: no interface
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { ...} 
}
```

Linq on the other hand is based on extension methods for `IEnumerable<T>`.

Your `DataRowCollection` implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. It is too old for Linq.

But there are some helper methods available, `myDataRowCollection.AsEnumerable().Select(...)` should work.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks Henk. My question is less about why foreach works and more about why the linq extensions don't though, given the fact the foreach does. This type does implement `IEnumerable`

Comment: @xdtTransform it also implements IEnumerable. It implements both.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.internaldatacollectionbase?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks for the update Henk, that explains it. Much appreciated, will mark as answer when I can.

Comment: deleted my comment to make a more clear one but Henk edited his answer faster. For Work around please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974159/convert-datarowcollection-to-ienumerablet .

Comment: Henk also added details of a workaround haha Thank you @xdtTransform - appreciate the help

Comment: I prefer the "Why" and the "How to work around" to be different to prevent ppl from  closing Why question as duplicate of work around.